# Calculate semester in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Morning all,

I need to calculate semester from a date stored in a column in Power Query like:

**01/01/2022 ==> S1**

**07/18/2022 ==> S2**

I've tried the built-in functions of Power Query but I only have for Quarter.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the method for determining the semester from date? Do you have another table with the start date of each semester?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.